# VPN with Network Connections GUI - no public addreses

Tags: linux-mint, openvpn

I am trying to setup VPN connection using Network Connections GUI. To do so I pick an option to import vpn configuration and manually enter VPN credentials. So far so good, I can get connected. The issue is that when I connect to the VPN using GUI I cannot open any public website like google.com or similar (but intranet sites are working fine).

When I use the same configuration file and credentials to connect with terminal OpenVPN (version 2.5.5) with command `sudo openvpn --config ./vpn-conf/client.ovpn --auth-user-pass ./vpn-conf/ovpn.creds` it works fine.

What option do I miss in the GUI so that it highjacks all the connection instead of using VPN for intranet only?